# Connecting to Oracle with PHP on IIS

Tags: php, sql, oracle, iis, ora-12514

I'm having all sorts of trouble...

Here is the code I'm using:

```
$c = OCILogon('user', 'pass', 'host');
```

I get the following error:

> PHP Warning: ocilogon(): ociopen_server: Error while trying to retrieve text for error ORA-12514 in D:\Inetpub\wwwroot**\oracle.php on line 26

Anyone know what the hell I'm doing wrong?

It's PHP4, IIS6 btw. I've tried this on PHP5, IIS7 as well, no luck.

Thanks for any help I can get... :(

Answer (score 2):

You must have correctly configured TNSNAMES.ora file, where is stored information about connection to database. Oracle errorr ORA-12514 says:

> TNS:listener does not currently know
>   of service requested in connect
>   descriptor

Function OCILogon have this syntax (I'am not PHP developer, so excuse me if I was not right):

> resource oci_connect  ( string
>   $username  , string $password  [,
>   string $connection_string  [, string
>   $character_set  [, int $session_mode 
>   ]]] )

In your example is on third position parametr "host". But manual says "connectin string".
This "connection string" must be coonfigured throught file $ORACLE_HOME/network/admin/tnsnames.ora file ($ORACLE_HOME is folder where is Oracle client installed).

TNSNAMES.ORA look like this(example):

> TEST_DB = (DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS_LIST
>   =(ADDRESS = (COMMUNITY = tcp.world)(PROTOCOL = TCP)(Host =
>   127.0.0.1)(Port = 1521)))(CONNECT_DATA = (SID = TESTDB_SID)))

Instead:

```
$c = OCILogon('user', 'pass', 'host');
```

You should use:

> $c = OCILogon('user', 'pass', 'TEST_DB');

...TEST_DB is service name from tnsnames.ora file

And yet for complementing (my file $ORACLE_HOME/network/admin/sqlnet.ora look like this):

```
SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NTS)
NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (TNSNAMES, EZCONNECT)
NAME.DEFAULT_ZONE = world
NAMES.DEFAULT_DOMAIN = world
```

And finally PHP manual example (connection string can be inserted directly into variables in PHP):

```
<?php
$db ="(DESCRIPTION =
     (ADDRESS =
         (PROTOCOL = TCP)
         (HOST = HOSTNAMEHERE)
         (PORT = 1521)
     )
   (CONNECT_DATA = (SID = SIDNAMEHERE))
  )";

$odbc = ocilogon ('user', 'pass', $db) or die( "Could not connect to Oracle database!") or die (ocierror());
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try using persistant connection oci_pconnect()... worked for me